# UIautomator with two scroll views

Tags: android-uiautomator

I am just trying to automate settings app-> storage

I need to scroll through the storage part in right pane(TABLET) but couldnt do so. i could only scroll the left pane with Storage, Display etc

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any tablet to test this on but my guess is that you just try to find a scrollable. This will find the first one in view hierarchy. You need to be more specific.

I suggest searching for a scrollable with text that is unique within that. For instance if "Storage" is selected in settings, then there will be a "Total space" item in the list you want to find. First find the top node of the hierarchy (search for a LinearLayout or whatever type the top node is) and then find a scrollable that has a child with the text "Total space"

```
UiCollection topNode = new UiCollection(
    new UiSelector().className(LinearLayout.class.getName()));
UiScrollable storageList = topNode.getChildByText(
    new UiSelector().scrollable(true), "Total space");
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way either. I found a workaround though.
In the settings app, under Storage use something like:

int width = getUiDevice().getDisplayWidth();
int height = getUiDevice().getDisplayHeight();

getUiDevice.swipe(width*3/4, height*9/10, width*3/4, height*1/10, 10);

Answer (score 0):

Try instances of the view as below, below example works for right pane scrolling.

```
UiScrollable scroll = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(1));
scroll.setAsVerticalList();
```